# Temporary 404 after overwriting an existing file

Tags: google-cloud-storage

in our application we have data that is statically available for clients to obtain based on real-time data that has been calculated on our backend, because of this we have a static object in our storage bucket that our clients make requests to in order to obtain this data, however we have notice that sometimes when rewriting this data if a client makes a request within a certain window, they receive a 404 error. This issue goes away with the next request, but it's creating a rather undesired user-experience for us.

Is there any way to prevent these 404s when overwriting an existing file?

Comment: How do clients get URL of the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate this problem as follows:

- Enable versioning on the bucket. That way attempts to download an object that is overwritten during the course of the download will still succeed (because the previous version becomes an archived generation, which is still accessible).
- If the object being accessed is large enough (or networks via which users access it are unreliable enough) that the network connection can be lost partway through the download and the caller needs to resume, make sure clients save the generation number of the object they started downloading and when resuming the download make a generation-specific download request (with a range read). This will avoid mixing data across generations.
- You can limit the amount of space consumed by archiving by defining a Lifecycle Configuration that constrains how many generations back will be retained. If the object is overwritten infrequently relative to how long it takes clients to download you only need to retain 1 archived generation; otherwise you may want to do some measurement to figure out how many generations is enough.